# Using a Dynamic Named Range inside a Sum Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
=SUM(IF(('Old Data'!$A$2:$A$10000=Tracking!A9)*('Old Data'!$B$2:$B$10000=$E$7)*('Old Data'!$D$2:$D$10000>$B$5)*('Old Data'!$D$2:$D$10000<$C$5),IF('Old Data'!$E$2:$E$10000-'Old Data'!$D$2:$D$10000<"4:00"+0,0.5,NETWORKDAYS('Old Data'!$D$2:$D$10000+0,'Old Data'!$E$2:$E$10000+0))))
```

is my current code.  I created a defined name Total

Total = `=COUNTA('Old Data'!$C:$C)`

Everywhere that I have 10,000 I'd like to return the value of Total. I've tried simply replacing 10000 with Total, tryed using the + built in formula creator. I can't figure how to insert the value into my formula.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a formula question to me?

You can use `INDIRECT` See this example

If I have `=Sum(A1:A10000)` then in such a case I can use

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&total))
```

In my example `total` has been defined as `=COUNTA('Old Data'!$A:$A)`
Let me know if you still want a VBA solution.

**SNAPSHOT**

The best way to check it is to highlight the relevant section in the formula and click <kbd>F9</kbd> to see how the values are calculated.

[image]